# How to scale x axis which is increasing constantly using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 columns `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` with 10,000 entries and I want to plot `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` on the y-axis.

In the x-axis, I want to plot `v1`, `v2`, `v3` points every 500 seconds until the length of column entries is reached (i.e 10,000 entries).

`y-axis=['v1','v2', 'v3']`
`x-axis=[0,500,1000,1500... ,len(v1)]`

I tried setting xticks:

```py
length = len(df.axes[0]) #number of rows
x = np.arange(0,length,500)
y = ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
df.plot = (x,y)
plt.show()
```

but I am getting an error.

Comment: It will be easier for me and the community to help you if you show the plotting commands you are currently using.

Comment: @Juancheeto I have edited by code, Kindly have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

How's something like this, it grabs every 500th row (and includes the last row) and plots it using [Pandas plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```py
df[::500].append(df[-1:]).plot(y=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], kind='line')
```

[image]

Full code:

```py
############### create mock dataframe ################
import random
v1 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10000)]
v2 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10000)]
v3 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(10000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':v1, 'v2':v2, 'v3':v3})
######################################################

# Select every 500th row, include the last row with '.append(df[-1:])', then plot it
df[::500].append(df[-1:]).plot(y=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], kind='line')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,len(v1)+1, 500), rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I want x-axis to be an increment of 500 i.e 0,500,1500,... and I have v1,v2,v3 values.

Comment: "and I have v1,v2,v3 values" what does this mean? Anyway you can set the ticks with this: `plt.xticks(np.arange(0,len(v1)+1, 500), rotation = 45)`

Comment: To better understand what you even want, it would be nice to either have A.) an example of your data **and/or** B.) An expected output image (even just a drawing or something would greatly help)